# Better way of converting sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>

Tags: c++, pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am receiving  `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` inside a callback function. I am converting it to `PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>` using following procedure-

1. First convert `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` to `pcl::PCLPointCloud2`
2. Later convert `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>`
3. Finally convert `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>` to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>`

See below the code snippet-

```
inline void PointCloudXYZRGBAtoXYZRGB(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>& in, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>& out)
{
  out.width   = in.width;
  out.height  = in.height;
  out.points.resize(in.points.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < in.points.size (); i++)
  {
    out.points[i].x = in.points[i].x;
    out.points[i].y = in.points[i].y;
    out.points[i].z = in.points[i].z;
    out.points[i].r = in.points[i].r;
    out.points[i].g = in.points[i].g;
    out.points[i].b = in.points[i].b;
  }
}

void pointCloudCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& pc_msg)
{
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> temp_cloud;
  pcl_conversions::toPCL(*msg, pcl_pc2);
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2, temp_cloud);
  PointCloudXYZRGBAtoXYZRGB(temp_cloud, *cloud);
}
```

I am wondering if there exists better way which is efficient in terms of time taken. Kindly suggest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283137/better-way-of-converting-sensor_msgs::pointcloud2-to-pointcloud%3Cpointxyzrgb%3E/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you want the example code from http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#Subscribing_to_point_clouds but make the

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
```

into:

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> PointCloud;
```

http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#ROS_C.2B-.2B-_interface :

> pcl_ros extends the ROS C++ client
> library to support message passing
> with PCL native data types. Simply add
> the following include to your ROS node
> source code:
>
> ```
> #include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
> ```
>
> This header allows you to publish and
> subscribe pcl::PointCloud objects
> as ROS messages. These appear to ROS
> as sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 messages,
> offering seamless interoperability
> with non-PCL-using ROS nodes. For
> example, you may publish a
> pcl::PointCloud in one of your
> nodes and visualize it in rviz using a
> Point Cloud2 display. It works by
> hooking into the roscpp serialization
> infrastructure.
>
> The old format sensor_msgs/PointCloud
> is not supported in PCL.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2